# Safari will not let me delete saved passwords

Tags: safari

I'm leaving my current company and want to clear saved passwords from Safari. I go to Preferences -> Passwords, select all of my accounts, and click Remove All. Doesn't work. I try to do them one at a time with Remove. Doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Using Safari 6.0 (7536.25) on Lion 10.7.4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't typically use Safari's password storage, but I just tested it, and I got the same results (also on 10.7.4).

What you can do as a workaround is open up **Keychain Access**, and in the search box, tip in "Web form password". That should show you all the passwords Safari has stored, and you can delete them there. Re-open Safari Preferences to double-check you got them all, but that should do the trick.

Comment: Where do I find Keychain Access?

Comment: In the Utilities folder in Applications, or just type it into Spotlight (⌘-Space)

Comment: Yeah, it's not in my utilities folder. I was able to find it with Spotlight, so thanks. Web form password doesn't return anything, but if I look in the login keychain, I see a whole bunch of internet passwords. I'll try deleting them and see if they're gone out of Safari.

Comment: Careful deleting the ones labelled "Internet password"—in my Keychain at least, they're not web passwords that Safari uses, but ones used for services like iChat, logging into file servers in Finder, etc. Your best bet is to look in Safari's password preferences and try to match up by name with entries in Keychain Access.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't going to just wholesale delete all of them. There are very specific ones that I can tell are passwords for gmail, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to use the "**Reset Safari...**" feature (in main Safari menu). With the exception of certain plugin data, this will wipe everything from Safari, including passwords, history, downloads, autofill, cookies, caches, etc.

http://support.apple.com/kb/PH5043